# Some video files not visible on Xbox360 as Media Extender

Tags: xbox360, media-center-extender

I have an Xbox 360 as a media extender to a Windows 7 PC. Most files in my PC video library are visible and play on the Xbox, but when I added some downloaded files to the Video folder, they would not appear on the folder listing on the Xbox.

I thought that it might be a codec issue. But after playing around with the PC for while, the videos suddenly appeared in the XBox listing and played OK. I have since added more videos to the video folder, but they are not coming up in the XBox and I don't know what I did to cause the earlier "missing" videos to appear.

All the videos appear and play in the Windows Media Center on the PC. The videos in question are in XviD format (I have other XviD files which play OK, in the same folder).

In summary:

1. Two videos in same folder. All are XviD in an AVI container.
2. Only one of the videos is listed and plays in Media Extender
3. Both videos appear and play in Windows Media Center

EDIT

in response to one of the comments; it's been a couple of days since I added the files and I've rebooted both systems several times, so it's not a time issue

Comment: I would say this is more of an issue with the Xbox (as on your PC everything works), which is why I think this is off topic for us. Still, you might want to use a video info tool like [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) to look for subtle differences between the video files in question. Or it might just take time for them to appear?

Comment: It sounds like your extender is not set to automatically update the folders.  I do believe it might be a setting.  Can you place other formats into the folder and have it update?